# Universal Reference and constness

Tags: c++, c++11

This C++ code doesn't compile, you get an error "candidate function template not viable: 1st argument ('const int32_t' (aka 'const int')) would lose const qualifier"

I know I can solve this by adding an overload for `Func(const T& value)`, but I'm curious to learn why this doesn't compile?

```
template <typename T> 
void Func(T&& value)
{
  // Do stuff
}

struct Obj
{
  int32_t Id{};
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const Obj i{};
  Func<int32_t>(i.Id);
}
```

Comment: Just remove the `<int32_t>` from your second-to-last line in the code, because this effectively instatiates a function `Func(int32_t&&)`. On the other hand, if you put it away, you can benefit from template argument deduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make this call:

```
Func<int32_t>(i.Id);
```

you are specifying the template arguments. This means the `T&&` in `Func` is not considered a forwarding reference at all. Instead, it's just an rvalue-reference, which is `int32_t&&`. As the compiler says, binding `int32_t &&` to a `int32_t const &` would discard the `const` qualifier, and the call doesn't compile.

On the other hand, if you don't specify the template argument:

```
Func(i.Id);
```

then the `T&&` is indeed a forwarding reference, which deduces `int32_t const &`, and the call compiles.